# How to add metadata to a mlflow model safely?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metadata, mlflow

When I train an ML model, I get some parameters that I want to store near the model to load them in production.
There is a function
[mlflow.pyfunc.log_model](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html#mlflow.pyfunc.log_model) that can get metadata as a param.

However this is not safe

> Experimental: This parameter may change or be removed in a future release without warning.

What I considered:

1. Tags. I tried to use registered models and add them to the tags, but it does not seem to work with long strings. Like key = "abc", value = "abc"*1000
2. `unwrap_python_model()`. No, this is experimental

How can I solve my task?